# How long does it take for a question ban to be lifted after I make the requisite changes to my posts?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Does it happen immediately, is there a schedule, or do I just have to wait for a little program to get around to looking at my posts? If so, how long does that take?

Comment: While you're here, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976097/detect-input-devices-connected-to-ios-device/26977668#26977668) of yours is extremely low quality and not really suitable as an answer, as it is only a link advising to read documentation. You might want to change that too.

Comment: And as far as I know the question ban algorithm is not made public. If you absolutely cannot improve on your existing questions any further, you must simply remain patient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you make the improvements to your posts, someone actually needs to upvote them. If that happens (and it's enough to lift the post ban) you'll be able to post again.

The system looks at {the mysterious post-ban scoring algorithm} each time you try to post. If you're still below the target score (which only Stack Exchange employees know and how it's calculated) you'll still be post-banned.

Just because you've edited your posts does not automatically mean your ban will be lifted. You got into the ban because the community found your posts to be not the sort of content we want (indicated by the downvotes) and you'll need to have shown that your posts *are* the sort of content the community wants, which it will show by voting up.

Comment: Thank you. Followup question: Should I call attention to my old posts, which have been edited since then? If so, how do I best do that?

Comment: That's up to you, but I'd counsel against it. The "Meta Effect" tends to act more negatively than positively that I've seen. You've probably already attracted a fair bit of attention just by your question. In the meantime, continue to positively contribute in other ways: answer questions, edit posts to improve them.

Comment: I'm assuming it's impossible to be unbanned by contributing to the community in some other way, correct?

Comment: Other positive contributions help. Answers, edits. Read up at [the FAQ for this information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/21960). Remember, also, deleted posts count against you.