# Would it be a bad idea to call attention to my improved questions to gain upvotes? If not, what is the best way to call attention to the posts?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to get my question ban lifted. I went back and made some changes to my questions, and now I feel that the questions are fit for upvotes. However, the questions are old and so may not receive any attention from other StackOverflow users for a while.

Comment: If you edit, the question will get bumped to the front page, and people will look at it & possibly upvote. Also, if you post a link to it here, and it is really good, people will look and upvote. It's called the "Meta Effect".

Comment: I maintain that you are providing some very low quality answers to some questions, which will ***not*** help you out of your ban, and could lead you to an answer ban.. Just googling a library that looks half-relevant to something or finding some documentation to read and linking it usually isn't enough, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976097/detect-input-devices-connected-to-ios-device/26977668#26977668) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29641122/4686625).

Comment: Beware of irritating users, or generally calling attention to content failing the standards though...

Comment: Another thing, please don't [repeat questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290259/215552) to meta.SO to gain that attention...

Answer (score 1):

Editing your question will naturally bump it. Additionally, users with 75+ rep can offer [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to their question:

> #### What is bounty?
>
> A bounty is a reputation reward you can put on a question to get it
>   more attention for exactly one week.
>
> #### When should I place a bounty?
>
> In order to get good answers, you have to put effort into the
>   question. Edit the question to provide status and progress updates.
>   Document your own continued efforts to answer the question. This will
>   naturally bump the question and get more people interested in it.
>
> However, if after doing this, you feel a particular question *still*
>   isn't getting enough attention, adding a bounty may help.